# number convert binoc

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, 4gl

Can you help me.
if convert binary to octal anyone can help me..???

this code convert octal to binary. help me for change this code.

```html
function oct2bin returns character ( input octalString as character ):

  define variable i      as integer   no-undo.
  define variable n      as integer   no-undo.
  define variable c      as character no-undo.
  define variable result as character no-undo.

  n = length( octalString ).

  if n < 2 or substring( octalString, 1, 1 ) <> "~\" then        /* a valid octalString begins with "\"                                */
    do:
      message "valid octal strings must begin with ~\".
      result = ?.
    end.
   else
    do i = 2 to n:

      c = substring( octalString, i, 1 ).

      if asc( c ) < 48 or asc( c ) > 55 then                        /* a valid octalString only contains the digits 0 thru 7        */
        do:
          message c "is not a valid numeric character".
          result = ?.
          leave.
        end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Groups of three bits can be converted into an octal digit. Divide the binary number into three-bit groups, convert the group to an octal digit, then string the digits into an octal number.

```
PROCEDURE BinToOct:

    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pcBinStr AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER pcOctStr AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    
    DEFINE VARIABLE cPadding  AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE iLoop     AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE cBinDigit AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE cOctDigit AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    
    /* Pad input with zeroes to make it divisible by 3. */
    IF LENGTH(pcBinStr) MOD 3 <> 0 THEN
    ASSIGN
        cPadding = FILL("0", (3 - LENGTH(pcBinStr) MOD 3))
        pcBinStr = cPadding + pcBinStr.
    
    /* Divide up bits into groups of 3. */
    DO iLoop = 1 TO LENGTH(pcBinStr) BY 3:
        cBinDigit = SUBSTRING(pcBinStr, iLoop, 3).
        
        /* Convert bits to octal digit. */
        CASE cBinDigit:
            WHEN "000" THEN cOctDigit = "0".
            WHEN "001" THEN cOctDigit = "1".
            WHEN "010" THEN cOctDigit = "2".
            WHEN "011" THEN cOctDigit = "3".
            WHEN "100" THEN cOctDigit = "4".
            WHEN "101" THEN cOctDigit = "5".
            WHEN "110" THEN cOctDigit = "6".
            WHEN "111" THEN cOctDigit = "7".
            OTHERWISE MESSAGE "Bad input" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
        END CASE.
        
        /* Add digit to result string. */
        pcOctStr = pcOctStr + cOctDigit.
    END.
    
END PROCEDURE.


DEFINE VARIABLE cResult AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

RUN BinToOct (INPUT "1010011100101", OUTPUT cResult).

MESSAGE cResult VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION.
```

Comment: So I want to output the result using the input I entered, like if I enter 100 binary numbers then the octal result is 4 and so on. This is what I want sir.

Comment: That's exactly what it does. Input "100" and the output is 4. Are you saying you want  an input-output parameter, where the binary input is overwritten by the octal output? Or do you want it to be a function instead of a procedure?